# Google Sheet: How to get the actual change when onChange event fires?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

the [doc](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#google_sheets_events) is not very helpful. Unlike `onEdit`, `onChange` event doesn't have a propety that includes the change made. How do I get it?

```
function onChange(e){
  console.log(e);
}
```

[image]

There is no useful information in this event object.

The reason I can't use onEdit is I am using some outside script to POST to this sheet and it won't trigger the `on edit` event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `source` property of the change event object.

This property returns the active spreadsheet, then you could use `getActiveSheet()`, `getActiveRange()` etc.

```
function respondToChange(e){
  
  if(e.changeType === 'EDIT'){
    const spreadsheet = e.source;
    const range = spreadsheet.getActiveRange();
    console.log(range.getA1Notation());
  }

}
```

Related

- [How to use OnChange() trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27984727/1595451)
- [Detect Note changes with onChange](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65818015/1595451)

Comment: Where did you get the information regarding `source`, I can't find it in the DOC

Comment: @shenkwen https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose you have this source code:

```js
const showEvent = e => {
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e, null, 2));
}

const setTrigger = () => {
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('showEvent')
    .forSpreadsheet(sheet)
    .onChange()
    .create();
}
```

You set your trigger with `setTrigger()` and every time a `change` event is dispatched, `showEvent()` will print out something like this:

```json
{
  "authMode": "FULL",
  "changeType": "REMOVE_ROW",
  "source": {},
  "triggerUid": "8302470070286889650",
  "user": {
    "email": "user@gmail.com",
    "nickname": "user"
  }
}
```

The trick is making sure you specify and `event` argument in your triggered function, in my case it's `e` as in `showEvent(e)`

Comment: This is exactly what I get from `console.log(e)` when there are changes made to the sheet. But I wanna see from the event object what changes are being made, what values are being edited. See my question update.