# why is my spreadsheet registering a change?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[repost from an erroneous earlier version]

My spreadsheet seems to be registering a change despite the fact that I'm not opening it at all.
onOpen is triggered when the sheet is opened; onChange is triggered when the sheet is changed (such as receiving a form submission):

```
function onOpen(e) {
  var range = ss.getRange("A" + lastRow + ":A" + lastRow); 
  ss.setActiveRange(range); //automatically scroll to last row
  MailApp.sendEmail("[email address]", "OPENED", "");
}

function onChange(){
  MailApp.sendEmail("[email address]", "CHANGED", "");
  [more stuff happens here]
}
```

I am getting CHANGED emails at random times, including 5 AM and such. The sheet is populated by a form (actually a JotForm which integrates with the sheet). So when someone submits a form I get the CHANGED email without the OPENED email. When I open the sheet of course I get an OPENED email and an CHANGED email. But how could the sheet be changed without being opened, and without a new submission coming in either? What could be going on?

Comment: I don't think that you get an onChange for a for submission.  You do however get an onFormSubmit

Comment: I might recommend console logging the event object from the `onChange` and reviewing the logs of one of those random executions to get some more information on this. Specifically `changeType` and `source` may be helpful in debugging. May get more help from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68027420/13771937)

Comment: @MiguelRiveraRios can you clue me in a bit more? I'm relatively new to this. The only way I know to use console logging is when I have the code open and I run it and I see what happens. How do I log what is happening when I have neither the code nor the sheet open?

Comment: On the left hand side of the code editor screen you should see a tab for `Executions`, it will show you the results of any times your code has previously run (whether it was initiated by you manually or by a trigger). You'll get some information at a glance, but if you click into an execution you will open the log for that execution. Normally this will not give you anything, but if you add some `console.log` lines, you can see those as well. I would recommend checking out [the event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) examples to see how you might log it.

Comment: Please provide a copy of the Screenshots of the Execution log, information how's your Google Sheets was integrated with your Jotforms so the community will have better oversight over how your project works.

Comment: Well, this is typical.
The changeType it shows is... OTHER. What does that mean??

Comment: OTHER could mean a lot of things, based on my existing knowledge with Google Sheet, onChange or any event triggers should not detect any back end changes on your sheets or form. So I suggest using a Time Trigger instead.

Comment: I just don't understand how any change could be happening without opening the sheet and without any forms being submitted...